# How do I plot a STOCK historical graph in  android app?

Tags: android

I wanted to plot a stock historical graph based on google finance in my android app .
The problem is I can't find the api for just the stock chart alone and I must try to find another ways to do it.

I thought of a way but don't know what whether it works

the steps are as follows..
1) get the details from csv file 
2) read the csv file
3) plot the graph using the information of the csv file.(WHICH I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IT)!

so if my steps above works , I would only want to know how to plot the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Use Charting Libraries like [JFreeCharts](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), [JOpenChart](http://jopenchart.sourceforge.net/) (google for more)

They include samples on how to use them...

Or You could use [Google's Charting API's](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Answer (score 0):

Neither JFreeCharts nor JOpenChart has not been ported to Android (as far as I know) and will not work on an android as-is, not will any other awt/swing based api due to differences in their respective Canvases etc.  You could try porting one yourself but its not as trivial as it sounds and you probably won't be happy with the results.

I suggest using a library written from the ground up for Android which has support for the kind of plot you need.  I recommend [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com) but there are others out there as well.